# Why am I getting a SettingWithCopyWarning when trying to filter rows in pandas? How can I properly filter my data rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I'm pretty new to data analytics in general, let alone pandas and python, but I've done a lot of searching to try and resolve this issue and can't pinpoint what exactly the issue is. I'm hoping someone can catch it. When I run my function, it works but I am met with the following error: **SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead**

I would ideally like to resolve this and learn what the proper best practice is. I have pinpointed the issue to this single row of code:

`region_filtered_data = data.loc[(data['region'] == region[:-1]) & (data['type'] == 'conventional')]`

The most common causes of the issue, to my best understanding, are when you're reassigning a value to some part of the dataframe, which is not what I'm doing here. I am just trying to filter my dataframe to only those records whose value in the "region" column matches the one I specify and whose "type" is conventional.

Comment: Hi! In your code — region[:-1] — what is region? Is it a dataframe or a list?

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your response, it's a string but it returns with an empty space at the end so I'm parsing that space. I want to get all rows that match a string.

Comment: Got it, try the code below. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately, I have a string called region that I am using as well as a column in the dataframe called region. I want to get all rows where the region in the dataframe's column "region" matches the value of the string region. I am using region[:-1] to change the region string from something like "Atlanta " into "Atlanta". So I want to check if the region in the region column matches the region in the region string.

Comment: Try the edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
region_filtered_data = data.loc[(data['region'] == region) & (data['type'] == 'conventional')]
```